# Inconsistency of linear regression model estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

Suppose we have sequence of discrete random variables

$y_i = \beta i + u_i$,

where $\beta$ is model parameter, $u_i$  for all $i$ are equally uniformly distributed random variables with the values $-1, 1$.

Least Squares Method for parameter $\beta$ simply gives an estimator

$
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}
$

We need to show that the estimator is **inconsistent**.
The problem is it is easy to show the opposite - consistency of the estimator.

**PROOF**

$
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i(\beta i + u_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2} = \beta + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iu_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}
$

therefore

$
P\left(\left|\hat\beta - \beta\right| > \varepsilon\right) = 
P\left(\left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iu_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2} \right| > \varepsilon\right) \leqslant
P\left(\frac{C}{n} > \varepsilon\right) \rightarrow 0
$

because we have the estimate

$
\left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iu_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2} \right| \leqslant 
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i}{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}  \leqslant C\frac{n^2}{n^3} = \frac{C}{n}
$

Where I was mistaken?

Comment: I don't see any mistake in your reasoning.

Comment: @gabriel-romon, thank you for the response. This task appeared in my probability&statistics task book. There is a possibility that the statement is simply incorrect

Comment: what's the name of the book ?

Comment: It was a task after the lecture. I'm afraid the only source I can provide is the link (please see task iii) https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gLUscnzz00G9rmRHRgo994kZAh4Vt2OBsYZGmUD9oYU/edit?usp=sharing